# Copy single file in to sub folders of destination root folder

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file

I need to copy a single text file inside a (source) folder in to all (480) sub folders of another parent folder.

To keep it simple (I will amend the correct paths later) as I try to work out how to do this I am using

C:\000\Test.txt as the file to copy.

The destination parent (root) folder is C:\00 with the sub folders
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3

I have no preference if it is via a .bat file or PowerShell or CMD script.

I have tried seemingly endless solutions from google over the last two evenings, none of which work and bat file from a post from here that looked hopefull also did not work.

```
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

cd /d "C:\00"                   // replace to full path to your root directory 
set "_source=C:\000\Test.txt"  // replace to full path to you file your file .nomedia

for /d /r %%i in (*)do tree /a "%%~fi"|find "\-" >nul||copy "!_source!" "%%~fi\"

endlocal
```

⁮I am at a loss on how to perform what seems on paper to be a simple task.

I would be very grateful for any assistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample PowerShell script that uses [`foreach`](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-foreach/) to copy the source file (*Test.txt*) to all subfolders of the *C:\00* parent directory.

```
# Set the source file path
$srcFile = "C:\000\Test.txt"

# Set the destination parent folder path
$destParent = "C:\00"

# Get a list of all subfolders in the destination parent folder
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destParent -Directory

# Loop through each subfolder and copy the file
foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
    $destPath = Join-Path -Path $subfolder.FullName -ChildPath "Test.txt"
    Copy-Item -Path $srcFile -Destination $destPath -Force
    Write-Host "File copied to $($subfolder.Name)"
}

Write-Host "Copy operation completed."
```

Answer (score 0):

- In batch file would be:

```bash
echo off 

cd /d "C:\00"                   // replace to full path to your root directory 
set "_source=C:\000\Test.txt"   // replace to full path to you file your file

for /d /r %%i in (*)do >nul copy /y "%_source%" "%%~fnxi" && echo\File copied to "%%~fnxi"
```

---

In bath file